# How to store text file with utf-8 encoding into AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am just wondering how to write a text file encoded with utf-8 into AWS S3 directly, without needing to save that text file (temporarily or not) into local computer. To be concrete, as shown below, I think I could manage to save the file, which was downloaded from the web and was parsed with BeautifulSoup library locally, and to store that file into the designated S3 bucket.

```
import codecs
import boto3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/732247/0000950144-00-012588.txt'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
text = soup.get_text("\n")

txt_path = 'report.txt'

# Saving the parsed file into local directory in the name of 'report.txt'
with codecs.open(txt_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write(text)


# Loading the parsed file 'report.txt' and saving it into AWS S3
# with the 'my-bucket-name' as the bucket name 
# and 'report_s3.txt' as the file name in that bucket
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
with codecs.open('report.txt', 'rb', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    text = fin.read()
s3.Object('my-bucket-name', 'report_s3.txt').put(Body=text)
```

But, I would like to skip that local-saving process and want to directly save that parsed file with utf-8 encoding into S3 bucket. Is there any good idead to do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `soup.get_text("\n")` not already give you utf8?

Comment: Side-note: If you have the file saved on disk, it is easier to upload with `client.upload_file('report.txt', 'my-bucket-name', 'report_s3.txt')`